# Swift: reading plist file

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I'm creating an update in swift for an existing app in objective-c. I used plist file in the obj c old version to store data and now I save user's data in CoreData, so at first launch after update I read plist file and set a dictionnary with values saved by user in the plist file.
But PROBLEM is, the values saved aren't in the dictionnary (only values that I set myself directly in the plist file in Xcode are in the dictionnary).

Reading Data.plist code:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Data", ofType: "plist"), var tempDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String: String] {
      print("tempDict = \(tempDict)")
}
```

Print result:

```
tempDict = ["key1": "", "key2": ""]
```

But there're values in the plist file (the file is found and the keys are in the dictionary but not the values). Exploring the container data of the app and the Data.plist, values are existing.

Comment: You are strongly discouraged from using that *objective-c-ish* API to read (and write) property list. Use `Data` and `PropertyListSerialization` which both `throw` errors. Those errors will tell you immediately that you cannot write into the application bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But PROBLEM is, the values saved aren't in the dictionnary (only values that I set myself directly in the plist file in Xcode are in the dictionnary

that means you need to change the main Bundle and off course this is not allowed , as you have to copy the file to documents and make any changes to it , then read the lastet values that you wrote to it , you may be exploring the contents of the copied file not the original that exists in  main bundle

Comment: But the file is already in the documents folder of the app container

Comment: Then read it from documents , your current code reads it from main bundle